# Importing a sql dump on freebsd

Tags: mysql

Hi Im attmepting to import a 100+MB sql file, I guess I need to do it by command line as phpmyadmin times out.

Any tips appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually better to do imports via the command line

```
# mysql -h host -u user -p database < dump.sql
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to the punch

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload the file to the server
2. Create the database (you can still do this in phpMyAdmin) and assign privileges to a user, let's call this database "dbexample" and the user "dbuser"
3. Import the SQL dump:

   mysql -u dbuser -p dbexample < your_file.sql

You will be prompted for the password when you enter this command.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the "--compress" option if you choose not to upload the file to your server.

```
mysql --compress -h host -u user -p database < dump.sql
```